# Deleting Row that It Shouldn't

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

Can someone help me understand why my code is bugging out?

The code is below and this is some sample data. Without fail it deletes the first row that has a percent.

[image: sample data image]

Thanks in advance :)

```
`With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    hcRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    p = 5
        For i = 4000 To 1 Step -1
        .Cells(i, p).Value = Format(.Cells(i, p).Value, "Percent")
            If .Cells(i, p).Value < 0.01 Then
                .Cells(i, p).EntireRow.Delete
                '.Cells(i, p).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next i
End With`
```

Comment: That little green triangle in the top left hand corner in the cells in column E, plus the left hand alignment - looks like you're dealing with text, not an actual number.

Comment: That is why I reformatted before deleting based on number. Did I do that part incorrectly and that's why it's deleting row 2 but not other rows where the percent is greater than 1?

Comment: oh - so row 2 is always being deleted but the rest in this sample data are not? I misunderstood "the first row that has a percent" - thought you mean the first row from the bottom.

Comment: yes sorry if my wording was confusing

Comment: Hmm I cannot replicate your issue - can you loop for `For i = 7 to 2 Step - 1` or some other subset of the data, step through and see if you get the same result?

Comment: I tried doing For i = 4000 to 5 Step -1 and it still deletes row 2 which doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print i`, `Debug.Print .Cells(i, p).Value` to see what iteration of `i` it's being deleted on? scratching my head here.

Comment: Replace line `.Cells(i, p).Value = Format(.Cells(i, p).Value, "Percent")`; With `.Cells(i, p).NumberFormat = "General"`
        `.Cells(i, p).Value = .Cells(i, p).Value`. Then run your code it should work.

Comment: If you get rid of the `.Cells(i, p).Value = Format(.Cells(i, p).Value, "Percent")` line, then before running the code you convert all the text to numbers manually (i.e. enter 1 in a new cell, copy it, then select column E and pastespecial > multiply), does it still delete row 2?

Comment: I'm glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

This line was not functioning correctly `.Cells(i, p).Value = Format(.Cells(i, p).Value, "Percent")`

I played with it in Excel until I found something that worked.  See below.

```
Sub test()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    hcRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    p = 5
        For i = hcRow To 2 Step -1 'Changed to take advantage of your detection of the last row, and stops before your title row
        Cells(i, p) = Replace(Cells(i, p), "%", "") 'Removes the percent sign
        Cells(i, p).NumberFormat = "0.00%" 'Reformats the cell (at this point, Excel still sees it formatted as text)
        Cells(i, p) = Cells(i, p) & "%" 'Re-addition of the percent sign to the end triggers Excel to see it as a percent
            If .Cells(i, p).Value < 0.01 Then 'Now your code works as desired
                .Cells(i, p).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I can't pretend to understand why this works.  It must somehow be related to how Excel understands numbers.

Before Screenshot:

[image: Before]

After Screenshot:

[image: After]

Comment: Some how that makes the problem worse. Before it would delete rows that were less than 1% in addition to row 2. Now it replaces the values under 1% with "%" and only deletes row 2

Comment: Hmmm...  I think, then, that something else is happening in code maybe you haven't supplied here.  See the screenshots I've added to my answer.

Comment: So your thinking that this is what's causing it? the line to delete the headers (which appear multiple times)? `If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Part Number" Then
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If`

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  However, I think you have the right idea to start looking suspiciously at other sections of your code that delete an entire line.

Comment: thank you for your help! It's working now. It was something like that